# invalid json with valid json (verified with online tool)

Tags: node.js, json, mariadb

## **Unfortunately this was due to another unrelated part of my code. This is an invalid question. Sorry.**

I am getting an invalid json response body error on my client using fetch() to a RESTFUL api.

This is my server POST code that is called by the client using this code:

```
.then(conn => {
        conn.query("SELECT MAX(`messagesMinute`) FROM `statistics` LIMIT 1;")
            .then(rows => { // rows: [ {val: 1}, meta: ... ]
                var data = {
                    'messagesMinuteMAX': Object.values(rows[0])[0] // ugly ass code but i dont know a better way after searching for a while
                }

                res.json(JSON.stringify(data));
                res.end();
            })
```

This is my client code that uses fetch

```
// Request the highscore of messages per minute
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/postRequestMinute", { method: 'GET', headers: {} })
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(async (json) => {
                console.log(json); // <<<<---- this is the log that retrieves the following
              
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

The console.log that sends out the json response returns this:

```
{ "messagesMinuteMAX": 1341 }
```

This is verified as valid with multiple online json validaters.

My biggest problem with all of this is that everything works as intended, but it spits out this error anyways which is very annoying.

Comment: Here you can   use res.json(data);   instead 
 res.json(JSON.stringify(data));


Add ""  to 'messagesMinuteMAX'   as "messagesMinuteMAX"   - Not sure if required Just keep it safe. 


Also add 

headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },

in headers which is blank there

Comment: and with all this  try  removing 

 .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            })

because that would not required in your case

Comment: Hello, I have tried both of your suggestions and they have not worked. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

After fetch API, try to use JSON.parse(object_string)
Hope it works for you

Tip: use `typeof(variable)` to verify variable type

```
let result
fetch("http://localhost:3001/postRequestMinute", { method: 'GET', headers: {} })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(JSON.parse(res))
                    result = JSON.parse(res)
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
```

Comment: .json() method is doing same there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its your

```
res.json(JSON.stringify(data));
```

This what happend when I did in nodejs console

```
> a = [{ type: 'text', text: 'Hello, world1' }]
[ { type: 'text', text: 'Hello, world1' } ]
> JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(a))
'"[{\\"type\\":\\"text\\",\\"text\\":\\"Hello, world1\\"}]"'
```

when you stringify 2 times you got 2 quote outside your object

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this was due to another unrelated part of my code. This is an invalid question. Sorry.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I would delete the question altogether if I were you?